# Does Kyouya get his Cursed Sword Gram back?

Tags: konosuba

In episode 5, Kyouya becomes shocked and runs away after finding out that Kazuma has sold his sword to the shop. He also says that he will buy him the best sword in the shop in exchange. He should be able to buy his sword back from the shop if he could afford the best sword. But at the end of episode 10, there are 2 scenes of Kyouya doing the rough work like he was starting from zero. And most importantly, it doesn't seems like he got his sword back since he usually keeps the sword on his waist.

[image]

Comment: I don't think continuity is the strongest feature of this particular title, so it might just not have any explanation

Answer (score 3):

He does eventually get his sword back. Just under 12 minutes into the OVA for season two, Kyouya appears briefly with the sword on his waist.

[image: screenshot of this scene]